# How to press Windows + s in pyautogui? How to minimize all opened windows at once by python script?

Tags: python, windows, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, pyautogui

I am working on personal voice assistant in python. I want to implement a function that minimize all windows at once. And I find a keyboard shortcut that is WINDOWS + D which will throw us on desktop. **So I am thinking to make a python program with the help of pyautogui module to press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> with python script.**

**But how can I press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> by python script?**

**Or is there any other way to minimize all opened windows by a python script?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pyautogui, you can stimulate a virtual click in 2 ways. Choose which one works best for you:

1:

```python
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'd')
```

2:

```python
import pyautogui

pyautogui.keyDown('winleft')
pyautogui.press('d')
pyautogui.keyUp('winleft')
```

Sometimes the first one doesn't work, so if it doesn't, try the second one.